# Android - Phone call when clicking on a TextView (API 14)

Tags: android, onclick, textview, call, android-permissions

I searched a lot for this problem but I can't seem to find a good answer for my situation. Basically I want my phone (Emulator on Android Studio) to call a phone number (101 in this case) automatically when the user clicks on the text.

If you have a better code or suggestions, feel free to share. Thank you

**XML:**

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/police"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/call"
            android:onClick="call"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:text="101"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            call(v);
        }
    });

}

public void call(View v) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
    }
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

I also added the following line of code before

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com...MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

in your xml you are using `TextView`. in your code you are using `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);`
they should be same.

If you want to make your textview clickable add this to your xml.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Then in your code you can do something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            call(v);
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: Tried this but I still have an error. 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

Comment: it still says you are trying to set onclick listener on a Button. something is wrong in your code. can you check again. Also, adding ```android:clickable="true"``` in your XML is sufficient

Comment: it should work. everything looks fine.. how about trying this. Since you have already set ```android:onClick="onClick"``` in your XML, you can actually remove ```TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.call);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            call(v);
        }
    });```

Comment: The app runs now, but nothing happens when I click the TextView :/ I think the problem comes from the OnClickListener.

Comment: can you post your xml and .java file again.

Comment: `public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
        }
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }`

Comment: `<TextView
                android:id="@+id/call"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/police"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="101"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>`

Comment: Let me tell you what is the issue. Issue is not with your textview or OnClickListener. it is with permission handling. if you are using android version 6+ you need to know how to handle the permissions. read this for more information https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: Actually I tried some code again but it didn't work :/ Thanks anyway